# Stock on Stock merger when numbers don't add up

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Company A and Company B want to merge

After merge, company A stock holders want to have between 51.1% and 51.9% of ownership, so company B holders have the rest

The problem is that Company A only has 1.000 shares Outstanding and company B has 20.000

Also market price of company A is $4 and company B has market price of $1

How can the merger be achieved with a stock for stock combination; meaning X shares of company A stock are exchanged for each share of company B stock

Also for merge to be accepted, company B needs to have a little premium. No cash involved.

Can this be achieved?. What would be the stock on stock ratio? What alternative solutions are there if the merger MUST take place?

Comment: Company A could do a stock split.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many shares are outstanding for either company. What metters is the end number.

In the end the combined company will not have A + B shares, they will have what ever they need to make it work and to make the people who have to approve the transaction happy.

They will perform two stock maneuvers:

- A stock split of A shares so that company A shareholders will end up with X shares for each of their previous shares.
- Company B shareholders will convert their investment into Y number of shares of Company A.

> After merge, company A stock holders want to have between 51.1% and
> 51.9% of ownership, so company B holders have the rest
>
> The problem is that Company A only has 1.000 shares Outstanding and
> company B has 20.000

For example do a split of 53 shares of new A for every share of A. Now there are 53,000 shares of New A in those shareholders hands.

Exchange 2.5 shares of New A for every share of B. Now there are 50,000 shares in the hands of the former shareholders of B.

That means the people that used to own the A shares now have 53K of the 103K shares or 51.45%. In this case there would be no fractional shares.

Other numbers are possible, but if integers aren't used then cash will be needed to handle fractional shares.

Comment: The thing I dont understand is why Will company B take the deal when their market cap (20k)  (stocks x price) is more than double than company A (4k). Stock Split Will not increase A's. Mcap. Where is the premium for B?

Comment: It’s your hypothetical scenario, questioning the validity of the scenario in response to this answer isn’t productive.  Yes it’s not likely a $20k company will pay half of itself in exchange for half of a $4k company regardless of share counts; but your question says that’s the transaction.

Comment: It's actually happening in the merger between Greenlane and Kushco. I just doesnt make sense to me, so I'm asking. Look at the market cap of both companies and check the merger details in the press release: minute 23:12 https://edge.media-server.com/mmc/p/ptkadao5
What are they doing? There must be an explanation